# OSX: Failed to listen on localhost:80 (reason: Permission denied)

Tags: php, port, phpstorm

I have downloaded PhpStorm and set all the required configuration. When I try to run the project on port 80, I get this error.

> Failed to listen on localhost:80 (reason: Permission denied)

And when I try to use any other ports like 8080 ,I get this error.

> Failed to listen on localhost:8080 (reason: Address already in use)

I have tried several different random ports. But I get this already in use error all the time.

I have xampp installed. And when I try to run the url in browser with port , it works fine. The problem is that it isn't working on PhpStorm.

I am stuck.

Comment: Try to disable xampp before you run your project in PHPStorm. You can't have two webservers at same time.

Comment: what do you mean by this ?

Comment: Who does throw the errors you listed above? And what do you try to do in PHPStorm?

Comment: **1)** You indeed need root permissions to run anything on ports below 1024 **2)** Based on your errors you must be doing something wrong (e.g. trying to launch new server at that 80 (requires `root` access) or 8080 ports (already in use by XAMPP as I understand). Please show screenshots of how exactly you are doing it -- most likely you are doing something wrong.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks, changed port >1024 and now it works fine.

Answer (score 14):

The errors description are very clear:

The error:

> Failed to listen on localhost:80 (reason: Permission denied)

- You really don't have permission to use this port; so you need to change your user or use *sudo* to run your application.

and the error:

> Failed to listen on localhost:8080 (reason: Address already in use)

- The address that you are trying to use `localhost:8080` is already in use by other processes/software.

Normally, if you change the port will solve the problem: (eg. 9090).

---

But, if you want to know which program is using the port **80** in Unix (Mac OSX, Linux), you can use the [lsof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lsof) command:

To do this:

In the terminal, you need to use:

```
sudo lsof -i :80
```

That will result something like this:

```
COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd       82   root    4u  IPv6 0x763617bed21ecc33      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd      226   _www    4u  IPv6 0x763617bed21ecc33      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

On this result, we can see that the `/usr/sbin/httpd` is listening on port 80 on my machine, which is the Apache server.

To know the details of the process that is listening on port 80 you can use the [ps](https://www.lifewire.com/uses-of-linux-ps-command-4058715) command:

```
ps u  PID_of_target_process
```

that will return a result similar to this:

```
USER   PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND
root    82   0.0  0.0  2463324   4248   ??  Ss    9:48AM   0:00.93 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

To kill the process by the PID you can use the [kill](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/ukill.htm) command, like the following:

```
sudo kill -KILL PID_of_target_process
```

After you kill the process the port will be available again.

Answer (score 8):

The PHPStorm / Intellij built-in web server listens on port 63342 by default.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+Built-in+Webserver+in+PhpStorm

You can set the port in the Run/Debug Configurations under **PHP Built-in Web Server**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop your Apache server from XAMPP.
2. Run your PHPStorm with ROOT privileges.

If running PHPStorm is showing your the same error saying `Failed to listen on localhost:8080 (reason: Address already in use)`. The `ports 80` is used by any other application. Try checking your used ports with a free tools out there. Stop the process using port 80 and try running the phpstorm.

Answer (score 0):

Xampp for Mac

if you find you cannot get apache to run and you have
no apache web server already running!

......in terminal type.....

sudo apachectl stop

......then run......

sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apachectl start

.....if you have a port not specified you need to go into 
    applications/xampp/xamppfiles/etc/httpd.conf and on line 52 or 53 
    you have a ip or localhost you can set. 
[adding a port number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVd6n.png) 
    add :port number example   192.168.64.2:80 or localhost:80 
    save and run sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/apachectl start }}}}}}}}}}}}}